# Converting date string

Tags: php, date

I get this string from the the API I am working with how do I convert it into MM/DD/YY

```
/Date(1298070720000-0800)/
```

Comment: do you know what that date represents?

Comment: The timestamp looks a bit long. Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: @saikios: .net serialized most likely.

Comment: http://www.bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/details/nostats/{apikey}/{gamertag}

Comment: Why did you copy @xzyfer's answer and then select it?  Select xyfer as the correct answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/\d+/', '/Date(1298070720000-0800)/', $matches);
echo date('m/d/y', strtotime($matches[0]));

// output
"12/31/69"
```

`0800` represents the timezone (in GMT I think) so you might have to adjust for that aswell.

The time stamp looks to be too long though.

Comment: That echos `12/31/69` it should echo `2/18/11`

Comment: It's because the time stamp is too long. It'd help to know where the data is coming from to know exactly how it's formatted

Comment: bungie.net/api/reach/reachapijson.svc/player/details/nostats{apikey}/{gamertag}

Comment: I'm assuming its. Net serialized, in which case it can handle 0/0/0. Add the seconds from epoc (1/11970) and I think it needs to be divided, too.

Comment: Please see a post I made previously regarding DateTime vs unix epoc times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998595/serializing-only-parts-of-an-object-with-json/4999004#4999004

Comment: I saw this, I have yet to find a way to convert ticks to unix epoc though

Answer (score -2):

```
// gets just the first 10 digits in that string
preg_match( '/([\d]{10})/', '/Date(1298070720000-0800)/', $matches );
echo date( 'm-d-y', $matches[0] );
    //output
    "2/18/11"
```

Comment: Are you working on linux or windows? Because on linux this returns "12/31/69"