# Convert int to bool on json deserialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a class that i uses `JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize<class>`

One of the properties i get from the UI is an int (0 or 1). Is there any way to change the getter/setter on the property in c# so it understands that it should return true or false based on the value? Or do i need another property that checks the int prop? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *best* way would be to create your own [JavaScriptConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptconverter.aspx) which can be used to handle your object and convert between different data types. Override the serialize/deserialize methods and parse the format as you wish.

Here's a link to a previous answer I wrote which implements the JavaScriptConverter, showing you how you'd pass it to the JavaScriptSerializer object: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4999004/298053