# Parsing Json String

Tags: c#, json

Is there a native library that would allow me to parse a Json formatted string? Say, for example, I had the string:

```
string inp = "{ \"title\": \"My Title\" }";
```

Is there a class where I can construct an object using that Json formatted string and find the value for `title`?

Edit: My app is a console application.

Comment: What kind of C# application? Certain projects (like MVC) have libraries available to handle this, otherwise you're looking at using another third-party one. -- e.g. [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

Comment: I am trying to find one that can be used from a Console app.

Comment: @BradChristie: You can generally use most libraries from most environments.

Comment: @TheDude: Both alternatives in my answer work with a console app.

Comment: @Eric: although you can, I generally wouldn't find myself including an MVC library in a WCF project just to use one object or feature.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212344/parse-json-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize a Json formatted string into an object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb410770.aspx

For better performance, if you're willing to install a NuGet package,

http://json.codeplex.com/

is quite popular.

Both alternatives work for a **console application**.

Comment: `DataContractJsonSerializer` is what I am looking for!

Comment: DataContractJsonSerializer has many issues.  Even Microsoft seems to be using Json.Net lately.  Watch out for DCJS issues with DateTimes.

Answer (score 3):

Not a native but a powerful one: [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
- Write indented, easy to read JSON
- Convert JSON to and from XML
- Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8.

Comment: There is a native solution now in .NET.  I agree though that Json.NET is generally superior.

Comment: @EricJ. I also prefer Json.NET, way more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of project, [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) may be available. Also allows you to create parsers that can populate custom objects.

Comment: A link to a previous post I made regarding the JavaScriptConverter can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4999004/298053

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Json.Net http://json.codeplex.com/  It has all sorts of great tools for supporting Json in. Net